# Why computed function does not recognize that props have changed?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

Im new to Vue.

I wanna know why computed function is not working as expected.
I want to change my todo.date (props) to specific form!

```js
import dayjs from 'dayjs'
export default{
  name:'To-do',
  props:{
    todo:Object
  },
  data(){
     return{
        isChecked:this.todo.checked,
        isModifying:false,
     }
   },
  
    computed:{
        getDate(){
             this.date = dayjs(this.todo.date).format("YY MM DD")
        }   
      },
    }
```

this is what needs to show up, but it's not.

```
<div>{{ getDate  }}</div>
```

my computed function should recognize whenever date(props) has changed and change it to right form!

Answer (score 2):

Inside the computed property you should return a value, not mutate a property :

```js
 computed:{
        getDate(){
            return dayjs(this.todo.date).format("YY MM DD")
        }   
      },
```

Comment: thank you a lot for giving me answer, but i tried it and it's still not working

Comment: oh I wrote conputed, not computed :( thank you though!!